# how to sum a columns in a table of a database but will get a total result by 3 different group of rows

Tags: php, mysql, rows

I got one table in database that have **criteria columns containing 24row (criteria 1 until criteria 24)** and **percentage result of each criteria rows**..

the thing is, I want to make a formula that shows in table like this:-

1. criteria 1 to 9, how much total percentage,
2. then criteria 10 to 15, how much total of the percentage,
3. lastly for criteria 16 to 24, how much total of percentage..

after they count, it will be inserted to another table in database..

that all...

I am just a newbie in programming..sorry and thank u very much...

Comment: How do you get the percentage?

Comment: @A5l-lE5 i tried but i think my code is too rubbish..

Comment: @LoganWayne by user input...

Comment: Please elaborate more what will user do, what's the output, what will happen on the database, etc.

Comment: @LoganWayne user will have a form that ask them to insert percentage result by each criteria,which have 24 criteria..so data will be inserted to the database, then when user click a button submit, there is a table displayed that will show column (type) and column(total percentage).. this table data will be like above 1 until 3..

Comment: @RdeqChix.. : even rubbish code is welcome...post it, so we can tell u wat error that code has and frankly, thats a better way than us giving u a solution from scratch!! :)

Comment: @RdeqChix..post your code ,your efforts are first ,rather then reading a new code ,modify yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanations are inside the comments /* */:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

$YourConnection=mysqli_connect("YourHost","YourUsername","YourPassword","YourDatabase");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ /* IF SUBMIT */

$total1=0;
$total2=0;
$total3=0;

$criteria=$_POST['criteria']; /* GET THE INPUT */

for($y=0;$y<=8;$y++){ 
$total1=$total1+$criteria[$y]; /* Get total of first 1-9 */
}

for($z=9;$z<=14;$z++){ 
$total2=$total2+$criteria[$z]; /* Get second total 10-15 */
}

for($a=15;$a<=23;$a++){
$total3=$total3+$criteria[$a]; /* Get last total 16-24 */
}

echo "Criteria 1 to 9: Total Percentage is ".$total1."<br>";
echo "Criteria 10 to 15: Total Percentage is ".$total2."<br>";
echo "Criteria 16 to 24: Total Percentage is ".$total3."<br>";

mysqli_query($YourConnection,"INSERT INTO yourtable ('column1','column2','column3') VALUES ('$total1','$total2','$total3')");

} /* END OF IF ISSET SUBMIT */

echo "<form action='' method='POST'>"; /* SUBMIT ON SELF */

for($x=0;$x<=23;$x++){

if($x==0){
echo "<h4>Criteria From 1-9</h4>";
}
if($x==9){
echo "<h4>Criteria From 10-15</h4>";
}
if($x==15){
echo "<h4>Criteria From 16-24</h4>";
}

$placenumber=$x+1;
$placeholder="Criteria ".$placenumber;

echo "<input type='number' name='criteria[$x]' placeholder='$placeholder'><br>"; /* FIX 24, RIGHT? */
} /* END OF FOR LOOP */

echo "<input type='submit' name='submit'>";
echo "</form>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

This code has been tested. You should too.

Comment: OP should've been tested? :)